# Elapsed time of test in jmeter is not accurate

Tags: jmeter

I am curious why the elapsed time of the current running test in JMeter is not accurate?

I set my thread group to the following specs:

Number of threads - 2;
Ramp-up period - 1;
Loop count - 60

I suppose that means that every second 2 users will perform some actions and the step will be repeated 60 times. Which means it will take 60 seconds to complete the test.

But the elapsed time of the current running test shows 25 seconds. Why it's less than 60 seconds? How can it be that my test is completed so fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter acts as follows:

1. Each thread (virtual user) starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the logic controllers) **as fast as it can**
2. When there are no more Samplers to execute (or loops to iterate) the Thread is being shut down

Your configuration means that 2 users will execute samplers 60 times, the elapsed time depends on:

- how fast JMeter can send the requests
- how fast your application can respond

If you're looking for a configuration where 2 threads are executing samplers for 60 seconds - amend your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) setup as follows:

[image]

If you have troubles in setting up the workload model it might be easier to use a [Custom Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) for example [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides extreme flexibility when it comes to ramp-up, ramp-down, time to hold the load definition, etc.

[image]

These "custom thread groups" can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Answer (score 0):

The requests inside your test will be executed 60 times using 2 concurrent users

For example if you have 1 request which takes 1 second it will take around 30 seconds:

Total 60 requests * 1 seconds (time per request) / 2 (concurrent) users = 30 seconds